# Application Error on start up - libcef.dll

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, google-updates

I have an application error on start up

> Exception Eexternalexception in module libcef.dll at 0013B2D0
>
> External exception 80000003

[image]

Only thing I have installed before this error was Firefox and I have removed it but the error still persists.

I cannot recall but maybe I have uninstalled few IDE's from computer before this error showed up. Maybe I didn't notice it on time so these uninstals are unrelated.

location of libcef.dll

C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$\Managed\68AB67CA7DA73301B744CAF070E41400\15.7.‌​20033 and C:\Users\malakrsnaslava\AppData\Local\Google\Update\Chrome

**EDIT:**
Thanks to 
[magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981) answer, It seems that the issue is with google update, but since uninstaling all google product and have wated for few hours before installing the again, the problem still presist. 
Process Explorer points to GoogleUpdate.exe

[image]

I am using Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Have you tried **replacing the DLL** `libcef.dll`. Here is a link to one: http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libcef

Comment: @malakrsnaslava,  are you using **Chromium** ?

Comment: Uninstall UPlay and/or remove it from your startup list, it took me, 5 seconds from a mobile phone to determine what that file belonged to

Comment: http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1081197-UPlay-PC-error-procedure-entry-point-not-located-in-dynamic-link-library-libcef-dll-Forums/page2 I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: I dont use Chromium and I dont have UPlay.

Comment: So search through your computer, update question, to indicate what paths it does exist in

Comment: location of libcef.dll C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$\Managed\68AB67CA7DA73301B744CAF070E41400\15.7.20033
and C:\Users\malakrsnaslava\AppData\Local\Google\Update\Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't click the message away, run [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), use the cross hair from toolbar

[image: Process Explorer CrossHair]

and move it to the Error message. This will highlight the program which causes the error message. Now look which tool it is and uninstall it.

Comment: After uninstalling all google products the issue seems to be gone. "To fully uninstall Google Update, uninstall any Google applications you currently have installed. Approximately an hour after uninstalling your other Google programs, Google Update should be uninstalled automatically."